# MDX : ParallelPeriod and leap year

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have data for several years. 
I have a problem with February this year when I try to get last year.

I think it's because 2020 is a leap year. But I have no clue how to solve this. I tried a lot of things.

[image: MyError]

My request is like that :

```
IIF
(
  Iserror
  (
    Sum
    (
      YTD
      (
        ParallelPeriod
        (
          [Date Facture].[Mensuel].[Année]
         ,1
         ,StrToMember
          ("[Date Facture].[Mensuel].[Date].&["
              + 
                Tail
                (
                  (EXISTING 
                    Descendants
                    (
                      [Date Facture].[Mensuel].CurrentMember,
                     ,leaves
                    ))
                ).Item(0).Member_Key
            + "]"
          )
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Quantité Facturée AEC]
    )
  )
 ,null
 ,Sum
  (
    YTD
    (
      ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Date Facture].[Mensuel].[Année]
       ,1
       ,StrToMember
        ("[Date Facture].[Mensuel].[Date].&["
            + 
              Tail
              (
                (EXISTING 
                  Descendants
                  (
                    [Date Facture].[Mensuel].CurrentMember,
                   ,leaves
                  ))
              ).Item(0).Member_Key
          + "]"
        )
      )
    )
   ,[Measures].[Quantité Facturée AEC]
  )
)
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just simplify to use the `CURRENTMEMBER` function?

```
IIF
(
  Iserror
  (
    Sum
    (
      YTD
      (
        ParallelPeriod
        (
          [Date Facture].[Mensuel].[Année]
         ,1
         ,[Date Facture].[Mensuel].CURRENTMEMBER
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Quantité Facturée AEC]
    )
  )
 ,null
 ,Sum
  (
    YTD
    (
      ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Date Facture].[Mensuel].[Année]
       ,1
       ,[Date Facture].[Mensuel].CURRENTMEMBER
      )
    )
   ,[Measures].[Quantité Facturée AEC]
  )
)
```